# Add double quotes to all columns separated by comma but not the comma which are already enclosed in double quotes

Tags: powershell, csv

What i tried is

`(import-csv C:\file.csv) | export-csv C:\file.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8`

The above code works but consumes some time to execute even for file size<100kb.(About 220rows and 50columns)

Example :

Content in csv

```
row 1 - textOne,"text with a,comma",,sample

row 2 - textTwo, demo text ,,stack
```

output should be

```
row 1 - "textOne","text with a,comma","","sample"

row 2 - "textTwo","demo text","","stack"
```

Comment: Since your comma is not included within double quotes from the beginning (that is a requirement for a file to be a true CSV file) I dont think its possible to solve this. There is no way of knowing if the comma is a separator or a part of the text unless its within double quotes or you use another delimiter from start.

Comment: What is your question? Is your code not working (for me it does) or does it take to much time?

Comment: @DanielBjörk ..the comma in the second field **is** quoted, so yes, that is valid Csv.

Comment: Ah, now I see. But then I dont see what you want to achive since you are just saying this works but its consumes some time.

Comment: @T-Me the code is working but i want to know is there any other way to process faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to speed up the process by using the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) to import the csv instead of using the `Import-Csv` cmdlet.

Try if this indeed is faster:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'

# you'll need to use the full absolute path to the file
$file   = "C:\file.csv"

# older PowerShell versions use:
# $parser = New-Object Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser $file
$parser = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser]::new($file)
$parser.SetDelimiters(',')
$header = $parser.ReadFields()

$csv = while (!$parser.EndOfData) {
    $i = 0
    $row = [ordered]@{}
    foreach ($field in $parser.ReadFields()) {
        $row[$header[$i++]] = $field
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$row
}
# clean up
$parser.Dispose()

# export the csv in UTF8
$csv | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```